# Запуск spring проекта из кoнсоли mvn tomcat7:deploy

Tags: spring, java

При запуске проекта вылетает вот такая ошибка:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project core: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1]

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)

.bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=$(/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home)
```

mac os 10.9

Comment: 1. Проверьте, с какой версией Java запускается maven (`maven -version`).
 2. Проверьте, какая версия Java указана в конфигурации maven-compiler-plugin (`<source>` и `<target>`).
 3. Если работаете в IDE, то убедитесь, что в настройках проекта указан правильный JDK.

Comment: Дело было в "Проверьте, с какой версией Java запускается maven (maven -version)." Спасибо.